# Does the output produce same image in both Median and Mean Filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two questions.

First, if i convert an image from RGB model to HSI model, does the images look different in color?

and Second, I am using pepper.png image in the matlab and my goal is to convert RGB image to HSI model first. Then I have to use both median and mean filter over the same image in both RGB model and HSI model. After doing all this, I found out that the output image when im using mean filter on RGB model is NOT EQUAL to the output image when im using mean filter on the same image but in HSI model... Is it the right output? Does mean filter produce different images when that is used on a image that is in RGB model and when it is used on the same image but in HSI model?

Comment: Answer for the first question: RGB and HSI models are different color spaces - different mathematical representation for (about) same colors. In order to display an image on computer monitor, you must convert it to sRGB color model (other models are supported too), but you can't display image in HSI color space.

Comment: so if i convert rgb to HSI then the colors should be affected as well right?

Comment: Convert RGB to HSI and then convert HSI back to RGB (for display). Converted RGB should be equal to source RGB. (colors should **not** be affected).

Answer (score 3):

Answer to first question:
[RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) and [HSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) models are different color spaces - different mathematical representation for (about) same colors.
In order to display an image on computer monitor, you must convert it to [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) color model (other models are supported too), but you can't display image in HSI color space.
*Remark: don't worry about difference of RGB and sRGB. Matlab assume images to be in sRGB color space (RGB and sRGB considered equal).*

Check the following code:

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
RGB = double(RGB)/255; %Convert pixels range [0, 255] to range [0, 1].
HSI = rgb2hsi(RGB);    %Convert RGB to HSI
RGB2 = hsi2rgb(HSI);   %Convert HSI back to RGB
max(abs(RGB(:) - RGB2(:))) %Calculate maximum absolute difference.
```

The difference is `8.8818e-16`
Conclusion: Converting RGB to HSI and back, does't change the color.

For executing the code, download: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53354-hsi-%3C-%3E-rgb-image-conversion-tools

---

Answer to second question:
NOT EQUAL is correct, because RGB to HSI conversion is not [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).
Filtering R and G and B, is not the same as filtering H, S and I, and converting back to RGB (order of operations matters).

"mean filtering" is not well defined.
I assume you mean simple 3x3 mean filter applied separately on each color channel.
See: h[ttps://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49226-how-to-apply-a-mean-filter-for-3x3](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49226-how-to-apply-a-mean-filter-for-3x3)

Check the following code:

```
RGB = imread('peppers.png');
RGB = double(RGB)/255;
HSI = rgb2hsi(RGB);

h = 1/9*ones(3);

%Filter RGB and HSI images (convolution of each color plane with h).
filtRGB = imfilter(RGB, h);
filtHSI = imfilter(HSI, h);

%Convert filtered HSI to RGB format.
filtRGB2 = hsi2rgb(filtHSI);

max(abs(filtRGB(:) - filtRGB2(:)))
```

The difference is `0.7774`
Conclusion: filtering RGB color space and HSI color space is NOT EQUAL.

---

Where are the differences?

```
%Convert filtered RGB to HSI
filtHSI2 = rgb2hsi(filtRGB);

diffH = abs(filtHSI2(:,:,1) - filtHSI(:,:,1));
diffS = abs(filtHSI2(:,:,2) - filtHSI(:,:,2));
diffI = abs(filtHSI2(:,:,3) - filtHSI(:,:,3));

figure;imshow(diffH);title('diffH');impixelinfo
figure;imshow(diffS);title('diffS');impixelinfo
figure;imshow(diffI);title('diffI');impixelinfo
```

diffH:
[image]

diffS:
[image]

diffI:
[image]

Conclusion:
There is a large difference in H, small difference in S and no difference in I.

The reason there is no difference in I, is because `I=(R+G+B)/3`.
`I` conversion is linear transformation (and convolution is olso linear transformation).

Example:
Assume 3x3 pixels
`r00 r01 r02   g00 g01 g02   b00 b01 b02`
`r10 r11 r12   g10 g11 g12   b00 b01 b02`
`r20 r21 r22   g20 g21 g22   b00 b01 b02`

Filter first:
filtR = (r00+r01+r02+r10+r11+r12+r20+r21+r22)/9
filtG = (g00+g01+g02+g10+g11+g12+g20+g21+g22)/9
filtB = (b00+b01+b02+b10+b11+b12+b20+b21+b22)/9
Convert to intensity:
filtI2 = (filtR+filtG+filtB)/3
==> filtI2 = ((r00+r01+r02+r10+r11+r12+r20+r21+r22)/9 + (g00+g01+g02+g10+g11+g12+g20+g21+g22)/9 + (b00+b01+b02+b10+b11+b12+b20+b21+b22)/9)/3
==> filtI2 = ((r00+r01+r02+r10+r11+r12+r20+r21+r22) + (g00+g01+g02+g10+g11+g12+g20+g21+g22) + (b00+b01+b02+b10+b11+b12+b20+b21+b22))/27

Convert to intensity first:
i00 = (r00+g00+b00)/3, i01 = (r01+g01+b01)/3, i02 = (r02+g02+b02)/3, ... i22 = (r22+g22+b22)/3

filter I:
filtI = (i00+i01+i02+...+i22)/9
==> filtI = ((r00+g00+b00)/3 + (r01+g01+b01)/3 + ... + (r22+g22+b22)/3)/9
==> filtI = ((r00+r01+r02+r10+r11+r12+r20+r21+r22) + (g00+g01+g02+g10+g11+g12+g20+g21+g22) + (b00+b01+b02+b10+b11+b12+b20+b21+b22))/27

As you can see filtI equlas filtI2 (the order doesn't matter).

Try the same for H (Hue):
See H formula in `rgb2hsi.m`:
`H(nz)=atan2(b(nz),a(nz))*(180/pi);`
`H(H<0)=H(H<0)+360;`
`H(~nz)=0;`

Now try some examples, and see that filtH != filtH2 (order matters).

Comment: thanku so much. this was helpful indeed.. :)

Comment: @RuhulMashbu consider accepting the answer as valid then

Comment: yes.. it was really helpful. can you tell me why there is a difference? and where these differences occur in the image exactly?

Comment: I tried... please make an effort to understand the involved math.